# Velocity of 2 balls with different masses on a moving train after the train brakes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, inertia

## Question

This is from my textbook:

> There are 2 balls of the same size made of rubber and iron respectively kept on the smooth surface of a moving train. Which ball will move faster when the train brakes suddenly?

## My Answer

In that start it seems simple. Let the iron ball be called $A$ and the rubber one $B$. The mass of the iron ball is greater as:

$$ 
(1)\ M = V \cdot  D \\
(2)\ D_A > D_B \\
(3)\ V_A = V_B \ \ [From\ Q] \\
(4) M_A > M_B \ \ [From (1), (2), (3)] \\
$$

Then we have to consider what forces are acting on it. The only ones I could think of were friction with the floor and air resistance.

If we consider friction, then we can easily conclude that the rubber ball moved slower as rubber creates a *lot* of friction. But since they mentioned the floor was 'smooth', I thought we should ignore that.

So all that's left is air resistance (denoted by $F$).

$$
(5) F = m \cdot a \ \ \rightarrow \ \ a = \frac{F}{M} \\
(6) Surface\ Area_A = Surface\ Area_B \ \ [From (3)] \\
(7) F_{iron} = F_{rubber} \ \ [From (6)] \\
(8) a_A < a_B \ \ [From (4),(5),(7)]
$$

That means the rubber ball will move faster than the iron one (and therefore that the iron ball will stop before the rubber one does).

## Another answer

But my teacher (who'd given me this problem) disagrees. Her argument is:

> Consider everything with reference to the train. Before braking, the balls are stationary (w.r.t. the train). When the train brakes, negative acceleration is provided to the train. That means the balls will move forward w.r.t. the train. But since the iron ball has a greater mass and so inertia, it will move slower.

which give the same answer.

#### Doubts

So my questions are:

1. Was my teacher's approach correct? Seems a bit unsound to me, but that just may be b'coz I don't have enough intuition for switching inertial frames of reference.
2. Are there any other forces in play over here? I could only think of 2: air resistance and friction.
3. Should air resistance be considered?
4. Should friction be considered? In that case, the rubber ball will be significantly slowed.

Comment: Did your teacher consider air resistance (or any other force like friction force) or not?

Comment: All that she told me, I have written. Now my hols are going on, so I can't ask either. Though I can bet she wasn't even thinking along the lines of a force being applied resulting in acceleration

Comment: @Trimok Are there any other forces that can be considered? I could only think of 2...

Comment: Since the question says "kept on the smooth surface", you're probably supposed to assume there are no forces acting on the balls at all.

Comment: By the way I tagged it as homework according to the [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) - but this is a good question according to that policy, so it won't be closed.

Comment: Consider a "rest" frame, in which the initial speed of the train and the balls is $v$. When the train is stopping, and if there is no force exerced on the balls, these balls go on at the same speed $v$ (this is the 1st [Newton's law of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion), whatever the movement of the train is. When the train has stopped, it becomes a "rest" frame too (the speed of the stopped train, relatively to the original "rest" frame, is obviously zero), so the speed of the balls, relatively to the stopped train frame, is the same, and is equal to $v$, too.

Comment: @Trimok What you say makes sense only if we are ignoring air resistance as well as friction.

Comment: Yes, I said "if there is no force exerced on the balls". If you consider air resistance, I think you are right, relatively to the "rest" frame (or the "stopped train" frame), the (negative) acceleration of the iron ball is smaller than the (negative) acceleration of the rubber ball, so the rubber ball will stop first.

Comment: However, your model of a constant force for air resistance is not correct, it should be proportionnal to some power of the speed. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_resistance)

Comment: @Nathaniel 10x for linking to the FAQ question. Now I know more about the policy as well as don't mind (and in fact see why) you tagging the Q as [tag:homework]...

Comment: @Nathaniel I cannot see how mentioning 'kept on a smooth surface' implies there is no air resistance. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Trimok 10x for pointing that out. I realize that my model was wrong. However, knowing this, does it really matter as the $u$ (initial velocity) is same and we're only talking about relativity, not absoluteness.

Comment: @YatharthROCK : I am not sure to completely understand your question, but, for instance, if, in another frame (not the "rest" frame, not the initial train frame), the 2 balls (and the train) had a constant speed $u' \ne u$, and if there is no force exerced on these balls, they go on at the same speed $u'$ relatively to this frame.

Comment: @Trimok In my last comment I was referring to you talking about the model of air resistance used...

Comment: @YatharthROCK : You have to apply the particular model and look at the results : if, in the model, the force does not depend on the density of the balls, then the force, while not being constant in time , is the same for the 2 balls, so the acceleration is smaller for the iron ball, etc...

Comment: @YatharthROCK in the real world, a smooth surface doesn't imply no air resistance, of course - but in the idealised world of physics test questions, air resistance is often ignored unless it's specifically mentioned in the question. "Smooth surface" implies that you should ignore friction between the balls and the surface, and it would be a slightly odd question if they wanted you to ignore friction but take account of air resistance, especially without specifically mentioning it. (Though of course, if the book has covered air resistance recently then it's different.)

Comment: @Nathaniel You have a point. And no, we're currently doing motion at a __very__ basic level (I'm in Year 9). But then I'm confused: if those forces are to be ignored, then the balls will continue to have the same speed. But since the actual textbook Q is framed in a manner that suggest the speeds will be different, there must be some other factor that comes into play. I'm confused about what all to consider...

Comment: @Tromik I understood the point about the over-simplification of the air resistance model, but I didn't get your last comment. Could you explain it a bit more via chat or something?

Comment: I think it's intended as a trick question. If you haven't covered air resistance yet then the answer is "neither of them - they both move at the same speed", and unless your teacher was making some other assumptions that I don't know about, her argument is incorrect. In the train's reference frame they both get the same acceleration, so they move in the same way. It's exactly the same reason why (ignoring air resistance) the two balls would fall at the same speed if dropped from a tall building.

Comment: I think it is easier to reason in terms of momentum or kinetic energy of the balls in the frame of the train station. They just do not change.  You know nothing of the accelerations used, except the integral of it.(what is Year 9 ?)

Comment: @babou But they only make you reason that the balls must be travelling at the same speed. And Year 9 refers to grade 9 or the 9th standard.

Comment: @Nathaniel Although not the modus operandi of the outdated, useless educational system, you might be right. And I understand your argument: basically people get confused by the cause (force) and it's effect (acceleration). Oh well, I'll just mark it as "depends"...

Comment: @Nathaniel Correct me if I'm incorrect: I think Akash's answer is the same as my teachers and I debunked it in a comment. Is that comment valid? Does it apply to my teacher's argument?

Comment: 10x everyone for explaining all of this for me. I just want to know, should I write an answer and accept it now that all my confusion has been cleared?

Comment: Yes, the argument in your comment on Akash's answer is correct.

Comment: Although, some people will tell you you shouldn't use $F$ because there isn't "really" a force acting on the balls. But when you get to much more advanced physics (general relativity) you'll find that the use of $F$ in this sort of situation is unavoidable.

Comment: I've made some of my comments into an answer in case you want to accept that, or you're welcome to make your own if you prefer.

Comment: @PeterShor Obviously; but the question mentions both are of the same 'size', so that's probably not how the balls are.

Comment: If the balls are rolling, and one of them is hollow, it will move more slowly. But otherwise, they will move at the same speed.

Comment: @Nathaniel 10x for that, +1'd. I think I'll accept my answer instead which arranges the information to answer my doubts. But SE won't let me do that until another 2 days...

Comment: Please continue any further discussion by creating a new room in [chat]. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own doubts in order:-

1. **No. It got to the correct answer, but was wrong.**

   I think she was getting confused between cause (force) and effect (acceleration). When the train brakes, the ball and train acquire a relative acceleration. No other force comes into play when one's inertial frame of reference is the train's frame.

   She was basically saying $ a_{iron} = a_{rubber} $ and $ M_{iron} > M_{rubber} $, so therefore $ F_{iron} > F_{rubber} $ which is correct. But then she also says that the iron ball will move a longer distance which implies that both the balls will eventually come to a stop while simultaneously claiming to ignore air resistance and friction. So then which force eventually stops the balls (as otherwise they'll keep moving at the constant speed otherwise as dictated by one of Newton's Laws of Motion)?
2. **None that I could think of** (which are probably all of them considering this is such a simple question).
3. **Not mentioned, but probably not.** In most idealized physics questions (especially textbook ones), air resistance is not something to be considered. This is to some extent implied by the phrase "on a smooth floor".

   **If we don't consider it**, then no external forces will be acting on the ball (barring friction) and **both the balls will move at the same speed** till they like slide off the train's surface or hit a wall or something meaning this was a trick question (which seems atypical as it isn't the modus operandi of the crappy, unenlightening educational system).

   **If we *do* consider it**, then b'coz of the reasons in the (my) original answer, **the iron ball will have a slight greater speed than the rubber ball** and thus will move a bit further.
4. **Probably not** as the question mentions the phrase "a smooth floor".

   Although it could be said that while this would affect the absolute values of friction, it wouldn't change the relativity, i.e., the fact that the rubber ball will experience more friction that the iron one.

   Also, considering it would mean we should probably also consider air resistance. And then the question becomes unsolvable as there'll be unknown variables required then.

   For that and the reason above, it should probably not be considered.

10x, @Nathaniel and @Tromik.

Answer (score 3):

If you ignore air resistance, the answer is "neither of them". There are no forces acting on either of the balls, so they will keep on moving at the same speed the train was moving originally, until they roll (or rather slide, if there is no friction at all) off the surface or hit something. In the frame of the train, they both receive the same acceleration, so they will both move in exactly the same way. This is the same reason why (neglecting air resistance) the two balls would fall at the same speed if dropped from a tall building.

The question probably wants you to ignore air resistance, but in case you're interested in how air resistance would affect the balls' motion, here are some details. It is again very similar to if they were dropped: they would both start out accelerating at the same rate (relative to the train), but the heavy ball would slow down less rapidly, so it would ultimately go further. The reason for this is that both balls receive (more or less) the same drag force due to air resistance, but because $a=F/m$ this force causes less deceleration for the heavier ball. The balls will be moving much slower than if they were falling, so air resistance would probably not have a very large effect if you actually performed this experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I did not look at the equations (I avoid it whenever I can).

I disagree with the statement atributed to your teacher.  The main
reason is that when the train brakes, you do not really care about the
braking acceleration, as a first approximation. In the absence of
other forces, the balls will just keep going at the same speed,
together. Newton was standing at the station and said so.  That is also true when the train only slows
down. Acceleration (or intermediate speeds) may matter when analyzing
friction forces, with the air or the surface.

Now, what interaction may matter, assuming the surface and the air
slows and stops with the train.

The braking force by air is the same on both (same size), for the same
speed.  The (braking) acceleration from that force is inversely proportional to mass, and thus it will have more braking effect on the lighter rubber
ball.

The second interaction is with the surface. The hard iron ball is much
more likely to skid than the rubber ball (though the lighter weight of
the rubber ball may help it skid too). Skidding consumes energy from
friction, and that slows more the lighter ball (though it is not the same friction force for both balls: different weight and different substances). On the other hand, not
skidding imparts an angular speed to the ball. Sharing the available
translational kinetic energy of the ball between rotation and
translation implies that the ball slows down in translation (identical
effect for both balls)

If the train brakes slowly (weak acceleration, hence weak forces, thus relative rolling speed can increase slowly) there is a chance that skidding is
avoided for both balls. If rolling friction and air resistance are
very small, the two balls may stay close for a long distance.

More precise analysis requires actual figures.

Comment: I did not know what year 9 means. I am not in the USA. I hope my
answer is not too complex.(forget my quip about equations)

Comment: +1'd, 10x for the answer. I understood the answer and it was quite detailed :) But I didn't quite get your second statement: "I disagree with the statement attributed to your teacher".

Comment: @YatharthROCK I meant that I disagree with the idea that the iron ball is
slower. There seems to be a confusion between force and acceleration.
I am not used to reasonning in terms of frames, but since you do, I
believe it is much simpler to take the train station as inertial frame.
In that frame, no force is applied to the balls, and they just keep
going at the same speed (or rather at the same velocity). If you want to consider various frictions,
then there are different ways you can reason. But all this is just my
reasonning biases.

Comment: No, that was not the source of my confusion. I'd mistakenly read the statement as "I disagree with the fact that the statement was being attributed to your teacher" and not as " I disagree with the statement that you had attributed to your teacher". Sorry...

Answer (score -3):

[image]
The answer is simple

look at the picture 
so train is moving in one direction with a constant velocity so there will be no force acting on the fall except mg. Now when the train applies the brake and start to descend with a constant negative acceleration $a$ so the acceleration will be in opposite direction to which the train is moving. Since the balls were also moving with the same velocity so due to inertia they will experience an acceleration in the same direction as the train was moving which is $Ma$ and $ma$ so now as you know $ F = ma $ so acceleration $ a $ of both the ball will be same but the iron ball will move to longer distance as it got more inertia than the rubber ball and you don't need to worry about the air resistance as it not mentioned in the ques and probably it is not in you syllabus too and since it is mentioned that the surface is smooth then you not need to worry about the friction too and if you want an answer with both two condition in action notify me hope it made your doubt clear ans yes your teacher is wright.

Comment: I think you are also getting confused between cause (force) and effect (acceleration). When the train brakes, the ball and train acquire a relative acceleration. No other force comes into play when your inertial frame of reference is the train's frame.

Comment: You are basically saying $ a_{iron} = a_{rubber} $ and $ M_{iron} > M_{rubber} $, so therefore $ F_{iron} > F_{rubber} $ which is correct. But then you also say that the iron ball will move a longer distance which implies that both the balls will eventually come to a stop while simultaneously claiming to ignore air resistance and friction. So tell me, which force eventually stops the balls (as they'll keep moving at the constant speed otherwise as dictated by one of Newton's Laws of Motion).

Comment: oh sorry i little bit mistaken with the second part kind of added my syllabus to it sorry---------and mg is just for showing forces acting on the balls nothing to do with the motion cause there is no friction